# How run update query in server?

Tags: php, mysql

How I run an update query in server.

```
UPDATE yourtable SET newdate1=STR_TO_DATE(olddate1, yourdateformat), newdate2 ...
```

Comment: Uhh, what i'm afraid is that tons of mysql_query suggestions will pour out leaving poor author subject to mysql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very good link on getting started with [php and mysql](http://devzone.zend.com/node/view/id/641)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [MySQL library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mysql.php) to execute your SQL statement.

Comment: I would rather recommend using the MySQLi or PDO extensions -- and not the old mysql one *(doesn't support features of MySQL >= 4.1)*

Comment: Yes. I would suggest to use MySQLi too, for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    mysql_query("UPDATE yourtable SET newdate1=STR_TO_DATE(olddate1, yourdate)");
?>
```